# NAN error while extracting ansys result in python

Tags: python, nan, ansys

I tried using pyasnys library to read an .rst ansys result file. I was able to read all the displacements at each node but was not able read read the stress values and strain value after a certain nodes. It showed up Nan error. How to read all the values without a Nan error?

[image: Nan error of ansys result extraction]

Comment: Can you check if the node numbers correspond to midside nodes? Nodal stress data for printout and postprocessing are available only for the corner nodes.

Comment: Which Ansys release are you using?